# How to convert graphics overlay into bitmap in mlkit android

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I want to just convert graphics overlay to bitmap .
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/segmenter/SegmentationGraphic.java

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of the [following report](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/494) which was already answered there.

Comment: This is also my question and I can not found solution .